# Need to call jQuery ajax page method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm new to jQuery. I need to call the method after some interval.

```
    $(document).ready(function pageLoad() {
        setTimeout('SetTime2()', 10000);
    });

    (function SetTime2() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "MyPage.aspx/myStaticMethod",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                    //$("#Result").text(msg.d);
                }
            });
    });
```

It says, Uncaught ReferenceError: SetTime2 is not defined.
What is the correct syntax? Thanks.

Comment: Are there any js errors on the page. If you are using chrome browser, hit reload and see, if there are any errors.

Comment: Try it after removing the brackets surrounding the function SetTime2 method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(SetTime2, 10000);
});

function SetTime2() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyPage.aspx/myStaticMethod",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                //$("#Result").text(msg.d);
            }
        });
}
```

1. You need to just define a normal function with your declaration of `SetTime2()`.  No parens around it.
2. Also, you don't want to pass a string to `setTimeout()`, you want to pass an actual function reference without the quotes or the parens.

Note: you could also do this using an anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyPage.aspx/myStaticMethod",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                //$("#Result").text(msg.d);
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```